# Can Joomla has a custom excerpt like WordPress, Drupal?

Tags: joomla

Both WordPress and Drupal have a custom excerpt, it's very useful, but Joomla seems doesn't have one.

Does someone know which extension can enable Joomla's custom excerpt function?

Thank you!

Comment: The WordPress Excerpt is an optional summary or description of a post; in short, a post summary. Maybe I am missing something here, but would that not be the text before the 'Read More' in Joomla (i.e the first sentence/paragraph of your post)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any extension, Joomla can do this out-of-the box using the native readmore functionality.

1. Add a readmore to your article, custom excerpt before the readmore.
2. In article options, set 'show readmore' to 'no'.

Now blog pages will show your custom excerpt text but it will not be shown in the article view.

Comment: My pleasure. BTW, for future Joomla questions you might want to try http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ first. :)